# In R, logical operators and formulae to extract rows from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, logical-operators, submatrix

In R, let M be the matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    9    1
[2,]    2   12    5
[3,]    3    4    6
[4,]    6    2    4
```

I would like to extract a submatrix m from M applying the distinct conditions

condition 1:  `M[,1]<6 & M[,2]>8`;
condition 2:  `M[,1]==6 & M[,2]>1`.

The submatrix m should look like

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    9    1
[2,]    2   12    5   
[3,]    6    2    4
```

I tried to use `m <- M[(M[,1]<6 & M[,2]>8) &  (M[,1]==6 & M[,2]>1) ,]` but it does not work; my use of`&` and the brackets `()` does not produce the right `m`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant to use the OR operator `|` between your two conditions:

```
M[(M[,1]<6 & M[,2]>8) | (M[,1]==6 & M[,2]>1) ,]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    9    1
# [2,]    2   12    5
# [3,]    6    2    4
```

`|` having lower precedence than `&` according to `?Syntax`, you could even drop all the parentheses. But feel free to keep them around if it helps you with clarity.

Comment: definitly better: the & operator was the source of problems, not the brackets. Thanks a lot, Avitus